# How to retirve an integer array from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, c++-cli

I am creating a C++/CLI application that connects to a SQl Server 2008 database. How can I retireive an array of short integers stored in a varbinary field. I am storing them in a varbinary field after converting the short integer array to byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortuantely u have to manually convert it. try use byte[] in C and varbinary in sql.

this might helps

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[binToINT]
(   
    @bin varbinary(max)
)
RETURNS @result table(val int)
AS
BEGIN

    if @bin is null
        return 

    declare @ptr smallint = 0, @size smallint = 4
    while   (@ptr) * @size < LEN(@bin)
    begin

        insert into @result(val)
        values(substring(@bin, (@ptr* @size) + 1, @size))

        set @ptr += 1
    end

    return

END
```

and after sorted

```
declare @result varbinary(max) = 0x
select  @result = @result + cast(CAST(token as int) as BINARY(4))
from    ...
```

but for me, i'll use postgre which is open source databse that has integer[] datatype

Comment: Thanks. That wasnt exactly what I was looking for but it did help.